# Is it possible to replace a file input with a Blob?

Tags: javascript, forms, file, dojo

I am working with an online application of which I do not have access to the source, but I am able to inject javascript on it via iframe because I can create pages in the same domain.

This application has a form it submits for file upload, and file inputs, think:

```
<form>
   <!-- lots and lots of inputs -->
   <input type="file" name="blah">
</form>
```

I would like to use this form to submit a javascript Blob for this particular file instead of a file from disk, while not disturbing the rest of the form. How do I do this?

Comment: You can use XHR2(ajax) to do this, specifically with FormData.

Comment: use a hidden input w/ base64 file data, custom handling on the server required.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of solution I was hoping for, but I don't have access to server-side code. I'm stuck with a terrible content management system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible to replace file input value with blob.

To do this you have to construct File object from it like this:

```
let file = new File([blob], "filename.ext",{type:"mime/type", lastModified:new Date().getTime()});
```

Then create DataTransfer object and add this file to it.

```
 let container = new DataTransfer();
 container.items.add(file);
```

This will populate file list of DataTransfer, which can be assigned to file property of file input.

```
fileInputElement.files = container.files;
```

As can be seen in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kartearis/35cjqtg6/3/), it is correctly assigned. Also, I tested the upload (with input in form with enctype="multipart/form-data") and the file is passed to server correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible with the new properties of XMLHttpRequest and [FormData](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata)

Thanks to @musa for his comment ;-)

Consider this (untested) example:

```
function sendFile() {
  var content = "<hello>world</hello>"; // set here the content of your file
  var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"}); // set the type of content (eg: image/jpeg)

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('blah', blob);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    alert ('successfully (or not) sent');
  };

  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

More informations:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

> Notice: [FormData is not supported by IE9 (and less)](http://caniuse.com/xhr2)
>
> This is the same for [Blob](http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder)

Comment: I've tried using FormData and emulating the POST data that the large unreadable blob of Dojo code on the page I'm modifying sends to the server, but no avail. I was hoping to simply modify the html element on the page and let the Dojo code take over and do its thing. If this were a personal project were I have everything organized and under my control this would be a great solution.